# Set service's version NOT by GUI, wix

Tags: wix, windows-services, windows-installer, wixsharp

How to set the `service version` as the `installer version`, using `wix`?

How to set it by the installer's coding, **NOT** by GUI.

For example : running service creates a .exe file in the bin folder.
[image: right click on the file-> properties]

Comment: I don't understand the question.  windows services don't have version numbers associated with them.

Comment: why not? the executable file of the service has a version.

Comment: @Christopher Painter- hope it's clearer now?

Comment: Versioning  your application files should happen before building your installer.  WiX just copies files to the destination and doesn't modify them in anyway.  (That would break code signing if it did.)

Comment: @Christopher Painter- I see. Thank you. Do you want to answer this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Versioning your application files should happen before building your installer. WiX just copies files to the destination and doesn't modify them in anyway. (That would break code signing if it did.)